# How to push last three elements of list to next list for n number of lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have multiple list like:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
[8, 9, 10, 11],
[12, 13, 14, 15]]
```

however, I want to push the last three elements of the list to the next, which gives something like:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4],
[5, 6, 7, 8],
[9, 10, 11, 12],
[13, 14, 15]]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add what you've tried already. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
data = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15]]

data.append([])
for lst1, lst2 in zip(data, data[1:]):
    lst1[:], lst2[:] = lst1[:-3], lst1[-3:]+lst2

# [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```py
data = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
        [8, 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14, 15]]

output = []
for i in range(len(data)):
    sub_data = data[i]
    new_data = []

    for j in range(len(sub_data)):
        new_data.append(sub_data[j])
        
        if len(new_data) == 4:
            output.append(new_data)
            new_data = []

print(output)
```